# Need help to this bash/shell exercise

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
read x
if expr $x+1 1> /dev/null 2>&1
then
  echo "$x is a number" 
else 
  echo "$x is not a number" 
fi
```

The output of this line `if expr $x+1 1> /dev/null 2>&1` I really don't figure out how things go there...

Comment: Discarding standard error is an *excellent* way to not understand what's going wrong in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your script like this (simple add spaces around the +):

```
#!/bin/bash
read x
if expr $x + 1 1>/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "$x is a number"
else
    echo "$x is not a number"
fi
```

expr tries to add 1 to the value of the variable.  If the status is 0 (value of $?) it is a number.  Otherwise, there is an error, so it returns 1 (value of $? again).

If you remove the redirections of the output (`1>/dev/null 2>&1`) you will see that `expr e + 1` outputs *expr: non-integer argument*.

Comment: Maybe add indentation like in the now-updated question.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of non-numerical inputs that won't cause an error with your approach. For example

```
$ x="3 - 2"
$ expr $x + 1
2
```

Quoting can help:

```
$ expr "$x" + 1
expr: not a decimal number: '3 - 2'
```

but you can still fool `expr`:

```
$ x=999999999999999999999999999
$ expr "$x" + 1
expr: operand too large: '999999999999999999999999999'
```

A better approach is to use `expr`'s regular-expression matching:

```
# A number might be defined as a string of numerical digits,
# optionally preceded by a minus sign.
if expr "$x" : '-\{0,1\}[[:digit:]]\{1,\}'; then
```

`bash` has much simpler regular-expression matching built-in, however.

```
if [[ $x =~ -?[[:digit:]]+ ]]; then
```